# Можно ли так сказать: "Возьми, рядом присядь"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, литература, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Фраза из стихотворения:

> Если тоже устал быть рабом,
>   Возьми, рядом присядь!

Допустим ли такой оборот в данном тексте и вообще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из энциклопедического словаря:
[**взять**](https://slovar.cc/enc/slovar/1761396.html)
2. Употр. в сочетании с союзом **да**, **и** или **да и** и другим глаголом при обозначении неожиданного, внезапного действия (*разг*.). Возьму и скажу. Взял да убежал. Взять да и отказаться.

В словаре синонимов: *возьми да и* = [вдруг](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?insa=x&ab=x&word=%E2%EE%E7%FC%EC%E8%E4%E0%E8). А он поди (возьми) да и брякни ему.

*– Ты-то чего ко мне присосался? Проходи!

– Проходи! А я вот возьму, да и того... **возьму, да и сяду**.*
М. Шолохов. Судьба человека

*— Нет, за руль сяду я. А то ты **возьмешь да и высадишь меня**.*
Н. Романецкий. Конь в малине

Отрывок небольшой, смысл понять очень сложно, но мне кажется, что в таком виде (Возьми, рядом присядь!) нельзя использовать фразу. Если имеется в виду эффект неожиданности-быстроты действий (а союзов-то в тексте нет!), то тогда в их отсутствие (теоретически) надо ставить тире.
[Если тоже устал быть рабом,
Возьми – рядом присядь!]

Comment: В стихах зачастую для сохранения темпа союзы выпадают. Ваш ответ, Рима, меня вполне устраивает. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

1) **Такого оборота не существует,** для обозначения внезапного действия сразу после глагола следуют союзы И или ДА.

2) Если даже (в стихах) **пропустить союз, но подразумевать его**, то о каком внезапном действии там идет речь?

Пример обозначения внезапного действия.: *А ты возьми и присядь, если тебе предлагают.*

3) **Поэтому нужен контекст** для анализа стихотворения и поиска для него подходящей формы.

4) В тексте может встреться **сочетание этих слов**, например:

*Если тоже устал быть рабом, Возьми мою руку крепко в свою, Возьми, рядом присядь.*

Comment: У Вас возьми (что?) руку?

Comment: Ну да, руку, это же явный повтор.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, выражение "взять, (да) и сделать" нельзя разрывать, и нельзя убирать союз. А если и разорвать, и убрать союз, то получится что-то невнятное, как в приведенном стихотворении. Я бы такое не принял.